# How do I use the "active" class correctly in correlation with php

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm having issues with the use of php to control if a navigation link is given the class "active" depending on what the $CURRENT_PAGE variable is set to.

Here is the navigation.php file that is included into every website page file.

```
 <div class="container mt-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?php if ($CURRENT_PAGE == "Index") {?>active<?php }?>" href="index.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?php if ($CURRENT_PAGE == "About") {?>active<?php }?>" href="about.php">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?php if ($CURRENT_PAGE == "Contact") {?>active<?php }?>" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the config file that sets the $CURRENT_PAGE variable:

```
<?php
        switch ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) {
                case "/php-template/about.php":
                        $CURRENT_PAGE = "About"; 
                        $PAGE_TITLE = "About Us";
                        break;
                case "/php-template/contact.php":
                        $CURRENT_PAGE = "Contact"; 
                        $PAGE_TITLE = "Contact Us";
                        break;
                default:
                        $CURRENT_PAGE = "Index";
                        $PAGE_TITLE = "Welcome to my homepage!";
        }
?>
```

For reference of my template, I am using the source code template from this post.
 https://medium.com/@stevesohcot/sample-basic-php-template-for-file-structure-with-example-code-47ff6d610191

Regarding the problem I am having, the active class is only showing up on the home link, even when I am on a different page such as the contact page. When I hover over the nav links 'about', and 'contact', the active class initiates, but only initiates when I hover over either of the 'about' and 'contact' nav links. Maybe this has to do with the bootstrap classes I am using?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv2Lg.png)

Comment: where and how is `$CURRENT_PAGE` defined? And the currenct problem is what: all of them get the active class or none of them?

Comment: @Jeff I just edited the question post to clarify your points.

Comment: I have checked ur code. it seems ok. are u still facing issue.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "/php-template/about.php");` do this and check output

Comment: Where do I use that line of code? @tphobe9312

Comment: just print before `switch`. also try removing `/php-template/` string from all `case`

Comment: Update* The output is bool(false) @tphobe9312

Comment: ya thats the reason. now remove `/php-template/` from `case`

Comment: You were correct, thank you! Now how do I accept your answer? @tphobe9312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove /php-template/ from case